# Post form field in a Modalbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a subscription form where the person fill out name and e-mail address. When the person hit "Compete Now" there is coming a pop up. Here you need to mark if you are having a workshop and your postnumber.

The form is working how it should.

But I would like that the e-mail and firstname is showing in the modalbox aswell like this:

[image]

Does anybody have a good suggestion to do this? I do not have access to the backend code, so the code has to bade in the front-end.

There is a [working JSFiddle here:](https://jsfiddle.net/jpn75kfg/)

```js
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $('#myInput').focus();
});

$('#btn-subscribe').on('click', function() {
let navn = $('#navn').val();
let email = $('#email').val();
let workshop = $('#mce-VAERKSTED').val();
let zip = $('#mce-ZIP').val();
window.alert(navn + ' - ' + email + ' - ' + workshop + ' - ' + zip);
});
```

```css
.newsletter-block {
background-color: #7c7c7c;
}
.newsletter-title h2 {
    padding-bottom: 24px;
    font-size: 2em;
}
.newsletter-subtitle {
    font-size: 16px;
}
.padd-70-70 {
    padding-top: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 70px;
}
.subscribe-form {
    width: 100%;
}
.subscribe-form .form-control {
    border-radius: 0px;
}
.subscribe-form button {
    border: 2px solid #e4a228;
    background: #e4a228;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.4em;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wraper padd-70-70 newsletter-block">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 d-flex justify-content-end">
                <div class="newsletter-title">
                    <h2 class="color-white">Join Suite Vacations to Get FREE <br>Travel News and Special Offers!</h2>
                    <h4 class="newsletter-subtitle color-white underline">Secret Deals - for our subscribers only...Besides it's FREE</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4  d-md-flex justify-content-start ">
                <form class="subscribe-form" onsubmit="return false;">
                    <div class="form-group subscribe-input input-style-1 fl low-pad">
                        <input type="text" id="navn" class="form-control" required="true" placeholder="Navn">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group subscribe-input input-style-1 fl low-pad">
                        <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" required="true" placeholder="Din e-mail">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="c-button b-60 bg-red-3 hv-red-3-o fr btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span>Compete Now</span></button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="mc-field-group input-group">
                    <strong>Workshop  <span class="asterisk">*</span></strong>
                    <ul>
                        <li><input type="radio" value="Nej" name="VAERKSTED" id="mce-VAERKSTED-0"><label for="mce-VAERKSTED-0">Nej</label></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" value="Ja" name="VAERKSTED" id="mce-VAERKSTED-1"><label for="mce-VAERKSTED-1">Ja</label></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="mc-field-group size1of2">
                    <label for="mce-ZIP">Postcode <span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
                    <input type="number" name="ZIP" class="required" value="" id="mce-ZIP">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" id="btn-subscribe" class="btn btn-primary">Subscribe</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code snippet error. You must include the jQuery library. It's in the options, on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is just pure JS and HTML, you can do this

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  $('#navnModal').val($('#navn').val());
  $('#emailModal').val($('#email').val());
  $('#myInput').focus();
});
```

and

```
      <div class="modal-body">
          <input type="text" id="navnModal" class="form-control" placeholder="Navn" disabled>

          <input type="email" id="emailModal" class="form-control" placeholder="Din e-mail" disabled>
          ...
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. Is it not possible to set in the value in the form field, there was just typed in? Now the forms are disabled and it says "E-mail" and "Din E-mail" in the forms.